# Integrate Bullseye Coverage with xcode

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, bullseye

Im using bullseye coverage to check the code coverage its pretty good in windows(visual studio),
however, now i have to test the code coverage in MAC (xCode), i hav xcode 3.2.5 and latest bullseye coverage tool..

Couldnt find any help topics anywhere on net on how to integrate them,
Any suggestions or links or steps will be very helpful.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

The xcodebuild steps worked for me.

https://www.bullseye.com/help/tool-xcode.html

Comment: ya it worked, but its showing only few files from the source in the coverage browser!! the actual files which i need are not shown!!

Comment: Provided link does not work anymore. Updated link: https://www.bullseye.com/help/tool-xcode.html